# git different result file history vs branch

Tags: git, file, commit, history

I am having trouble with our repository : 
showing the particular file history I get less commits, than showing the complete branch/repository history.
(Clear that it differs, but some commits - containing particular files - do not appear, if I am displaying the file related history.)
Even worse, a checkout of the newer commits, are giving back older versions, than the last commit of the file.
Example : 
a.c is in branch history 5 times shown.
If I am displaying the file history of a.c, I get for example one commit less shown.
Repository is up to date (local and remote)
I am using egit / eclipse - but console has same effects

When I am checking out the last commit/or branch - I get an older version of a.c
than the last committed one !
Or when I am newly cloning the repository I get a much older state (of some files) than than the current one - in my normal repository

How can this happen ?
How can this be solved ?

Thanks in advance

CS

I will try to add an example :

`| path |     BLOB  |      date             |   Commit  | user Name |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   16.12.2016 16:24    |   23e4d4  |   User1   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   16.12.2016 12:35    |   f517a0  |   User2   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   16.12.2016 12:33    |   4b52b2  |   User2   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   16.12.2016 11:25    |   f17354  |   User3   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   16.12.2016 10:43    |   9f377e  |   User2   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   16.12.2016 10:43    |   a04e31  |   User2   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   15.12.2016 19:39    |   b47203  |   User1   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   15.12.2016 19:38    |   048600  |   User1   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   15.12.2016 17:55    |   f10cbc  |   User4   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   15.12.2016 17:30    |   c26862  |   User5   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   15.12.2016 17:28    |   66635d  |   User5   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   15.12.2016 16:49    |   e72066  |   User4   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   15.12.2016 16:26    |   fb1dee  |   User5   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   15.12.2016 16:26    |   d205a7  |   User5   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   14.12.2016 15:13    |   8f78e3  |   User3   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   14.12.2016 15:09    |   404690  |   User3   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   14.12.2016 15:04    |   bbab2a  |   User3   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   14.12.2016 14:19    |   2180aa  |   User6   |
|   a.c |   227bd1  |   14.12.2016 14:18    |   ce4dc7  |   User6   |
|   a.c |   227bd1  |   14.12.2016 13:21    |   4c135c  |   User6   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   14.12.2016 10:39    |   0fd1c3  |   User7   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   14.12.2016 10:22    |   839ec8  |   User7   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   13.12.2016 18:13    |   860ef7  |   User2   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   13.12.2016 18:11    |   7d752b  |   User2   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   13.12.2016 16:42    |   5a7770  |   User5   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   13.12.2016 15:50    |   c4a173  |   User5   |
|   a.c |   227bd1  |   13.12.2016 14:15    |   1a6044  |   User6   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   13.12.2016 11:55    |   02852f  |   User3   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   13.12.2016 11:26    |   506d9f  |   User3   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   13.12.2016 11:15    |   be6b93  |   User3   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   13.12.2016 09:38    |   8491a3  |   User2   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   12.12.2016 13:26    |   7ac6ce  |   User8   |
|   a.c |   227bd1  |   12.12.2016 09:44    |   b47bd1  |   User6   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   09.12.2016 08:28    |   cdbca3  |   User7   |
|   a.c |   227bd1  |   09.12.2016 06:45    |   6ab615  |   User6   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   08.12.2016 17:11    |   078964  |   User2   |
|   a.c |   227bd1  |   08.12.2016 15:44    |   f14d9f  |   User6   |
|   a.c |   227bd1  |   08.12.2016 15:12    |   38ea88  |   User6   |
|   a.c |   227bd1  |   08.12.2016 15:12    |   f577aa  |   User6   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   08.12.2016 07:54    |   d5ba9e  |   User7   |
|   a.c |   227bd1  |   07.12.2016 14:50    |   2ee1e6  |   User6   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   06.12.2016 16:18    |   49fab0  |   User2   |
|   a.c |   074aba  |   06.12.2016 13:25    |   1921dd  |   User8   |`

How can it happen, that - without any conflict message - the most recent version 227bd1 is multiple times overwritten ? - by different users.
Originally introduced by user 6, who updated repeatingly with his version.
Multiple users are committing and  pushing to one central repository an branch master.
The table was build of git ls-tree and git log  pulled together into a database to have the commit and BLOB in one view

Help and ideas are very appreciated.
For us it is not clear, if we are using git in a wrong way, or how we get it corrupted. Or may be we have wrong expectations to the git repository.

thanks in advance
CS

Comment: We need more info. A pic of the tree (gitk) would help, and a git status before and after checkout.

Comment: Show the actual console commands you are running, complete with all flags and arguments, e.g., `git log foobranch` vs `git log --full-history -- a.c`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick response.

Comment: I am afraid, that I am not allowed to publish company internal data :-( Even there is nothing critical - I might get in trouble. So I need to solve it from a more theoretical perspective. The problem might be related to single file commits and may be mixed use of "normal" commits. We have many many independent files - but set up all as one repository - not my idea.

Comment: In that case, reproduce the problem in a different repository that you *can* allow people to look at. Solve the reproduced problem and see if the solution carries over. Otherwise there is little anyone here can do to help.

Comment: Are you writing this as "an experienced git user" who believes this is somehow a git but or a strangely corrupted repository, or are you writing this as a "git beginner" who might in fact just be misunderstanding things and using the wrong commands?

Comment: Hi, I think I am experienced - not an expert. And I am not alone - we have been working for about 2 years now with this repository - and did not face issues like this. It appears difficult to reproduce the error - so I do not believe it is a wrong command. Example: I could cherry-pick a "lost" committed change on the same branch - so this version is recognized by the repository on checkout again. On a test repo this does not work - because it is already on the branch. How could I identify since when this corruption appeared ? Or get all dangling commits - so cherry-pick would recreate them ?

Comment: By the way - a git fsck --full showed me three dangling blobs - nothing more. When I tried to analyze them, I found that they are newer than the issues we have with some of the committed files - that do not appear in their most recent version on a checkout of the branch.

Comment: So from my perspective a special question : Is it/ how might it be possible, to create a commit, not reflecting the "snap shot" of the complete working area ? Because that is the situation I think we have. Commits, not reflecting the most recent status. Under normal conditions, merge conflicts would have appeared - like I tried with a test repository - with no chance to corrupt it.

Comment: I would like to add some news of my investigation  - but how can I add a table in the "limited" comment field ? or upload the table - how could I preview what I am typing here ? ENTER last time just submitted my text

Answer (score 0):

Ok meanwhile we know the root cause : 
we have been confused on a very "old" pending commit/push of a new user.
All users use pull (instead of fetch + merge) This user got a long list of changed files (in the index) due to one single conflicting file + all others that he never touched. When he solved his conflict, he removed all files, he never touched from the index - and later hard reset. Since commits consist of all files, *but not explicitly changed are not visible* as part of the commit, such issues are nearly impossible to find !
Consistency checks of such issues would be a nice feature. (More recent merge commits should not contain older file versions)